# How to iterate over an $http.get in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, iteration

So I am using an API (pokemon api) to get pokemon info.

I have successfully called information, however I am unsure how to get multiples of one item.

For example,

```
$http.get("http://pokeapi.co/" + data.abilities[0].resource_uri)
            .success(function(data){
              console.log(data.name)
              $scope.ability = data;
            })
```

Here I had to resort to specifying which object within the abilities array (with the [0]) but I would like to be able to get all the available abilities.

Should I use a for in loop? If so, can I do that within the .success and have it output what it finds within my html file?  For example have

```
<p>{{ability.name}}</p>
```

output 2 or 3 names instead of the 1.

Comment: What does pokemon api returns on your success callback?

Comment: And `$http.success()` is deprecated, a better aproach is `$http.then()`.

Comment: You can use the For In loop, Foreach, etc... in JavaScript, ensuring the promise has returned, or even the ngRepeat in Angular for HTML.

Comment: I'd like to use `ngRepeat` with some filter like `sort` in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This retrieves every attribute name for every pokemon in the api and displays it in an ng-repeat.

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/z5aytdLs/

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="PromiseCtrl">
    <p></p>
    <p ng-repeat="name in pokeAttrNames">{{name}}</p>
</div>
</div>

function PromiseCtrl($scope, $http) {
$scope.pokeAttrNames =[];   

$http.get('http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokedex/1/')
     .then(function(result){
           result.data.pokemon.forEach(function(poke){
              $http.get('http://pokeapi.co/' + poke.resource_uri)
                   .then(function(value) {
                       $scope.pokeAttrNames.push(value.data.name);
                    });
            });
       });   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped visualize what I am looking for.

Comment: Have any suggestions for storing the data temporarily so it does not go to retrieve the information for every request?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q take a look at $q. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Sounds like it might be a good idea to start a new question though or research "handling serial http requests with angular"

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code a little cleaner by adding your $resource and calling your methods from the factory in the controler, all I added was a for loop to do every request.

```
  MyApp.controller('PromiseCtrl', function ($scope, $http, yourResource) { 

             for(var i in data.abilities) {
                 yourResource.save({abilities_uri: data.abilities[i].resource_uri}, function (response) {
                     console.log(data.abilities[i].resource_uri)
                    $scope.ability = data;
                 };
    }).factory('yourResource', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
              return $resource('http://pokeapi.co/:abilities_uri', {} {
                    'get': {
                      method: 'GET',
                      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
                    }
                  });
              }]);
    }
```

PD: this might need a tweak, for example your $scope.ability should probably be an array

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot!